# Change position of bars of a Pandas histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I'm plotting several histograms using Pandas `hist` method.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {"columns":["a","b","c","d","e"],"index":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364,365,366,367,368,369,370,371,372,373,374,375,376,377,378,379,380,381,382,383,384,385,386,387,388,389,390,391,392,393,394,395,396,397,398,399,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426,427,428,429,430,431,432,433,434,435,436,437,438,439,440,441,442,443,444,445,446,447,448,449,450,451,452,453,454,455,456,457,458,459,460,461,462,463,464,465,466,467,468,469,470,471,472,473,474,475,476,477,478,479,480,481,482,483,484,485,486,487,488,489,490,491,492,493,494,495,496,497,498,499],"data":[[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0],[0,0,0,-2,0],[0,0,4,0,-2],[3,1,0,-1,-2],[1,2,0,-1,-2],[1,0,0,-1,-2],[1,2,2,0,0],[-1,2,0,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,0],[-1,2,0,-1,-1],[3,0,1,-1,-1],[-2,0,-1,0,1],[-1,1,0,1,-2],[0,0,0,0,-2],[-1,2,0,-1,0],[0,0,-1,-2,0]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d['data'], columns=d['columns'], index=d['index'])
bins = np.arange(-5, 5+1, 0.5)
_ = df.hist(figsize=(12, 10), bins=bins)
```

I'm getting the following histograms:

[image: hist]

I'd like to have bars either centered on x-labels (-2, -1, 0, 1, 3) for "a" histogram or have bars at the left of x-labels

I'm looking at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to center the bars you can do

```
_ = df.hist(figsize=(12, 10), bins=bins, align='left')
```